# Magento 1.5.1 getting product images using php

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

This code gets contents(images) in a magento store. It is able to fetch images for magento 1.4x - 1.5
I tried it in 1.5.1 and it seems it cannot fetch the images. Is it located in "media/catalog/product" ?
Any help in getting the location of magento 1.5.1 images? Thanks.

```
<?php
  include_once 'app/Mage.php';
  umask(0);
  Mage::app();


$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->load(); 

$baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);


   $myImage = $baseUrl ."media/catalog/product". $product['image'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  include_once 'app/Mage.php';
  umask(0);
  Mage::app();


$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail');
$products->load();
$product = $products->getData('thumbnail');

$baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);

   $myImage = $baseUrl ."media/catalog/product". $product[2]['thumbnail'];
   print $myImage;
?>
```

Obviously you'll want to loop over the collection or specify a product ID in your collection for a specific product, I just used an index of [2] for show.

Also no need to load the entire product attributes collection with `*` but rather the specific attribute your needing to conserve memory space.

Comment: how to get all the images from the gallery - instead of just thumbnail?

Comment: @SantoshAchari See the 2nd sentence of the answer, change `addAttributeToSelect` to `*` instead of `thumbnail` and adjust array indexes to relevant attribute.

Comment: And it throws all the attributes. Not just images.